# Michelson interferometers and earth's rotation

Tags: rotation, interferometry

Has anyone ever deliberately/specifically tried to detect earth's rotation on its axis using a Michelson interferometer?

Comment: You might get more responses if you move this post to hsm.se

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this was the not-quite-famous [Michelson Gale experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Gale%E2%80%93Pearson_experiment).

Note that the design of the Michelson Gale interferometer is substantially different from the Michelson Morley interferometer. The Michelson Morley interferometer is not sensitive to rotation.

Now this type of experiment is commonly done using laser ring interferometers, which are routinely incorporated into commercially manufactured inertial navigation units.

Comment: Why is the Michelson-Morley interferometer not sensitive to rotation?

Comment: @mmx_in_orbit because the area enclosed by the light path is 0

Comment: Perfect! +1. -NN